# PDOException: could not find driver - pdo_mysql enabled

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, mamp

I’ve been struggling trying to **connect PHP to MySQL using the PDO()** constructor since yesterday, and despite all the answers I’ve found on this problem, none of them worked.

In phpMyAdmin I have a database called ‘database_test’ and I’m trying to connect to it.

I’ve tried with ‘localhost’ and with ‘localhost:3306’:

```
<?php $mysqlConnection = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=database_test;charset=utf8','root','root');?>
```

Both returning the same error when accessing http://localhost:8080/home.php :

> **Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: could not find driver** in
> C:\Users...\home.php:3 Stack trace: #0 C:\Users...\home.php(3):
> PDO->__construct('mysql:host=loca...', 'root', 'root') #1 {main}
> thrown in C:\Users...\home.php on line 3

Yet, the module **pdo_mysql is enabled**

Mamp says : “To connect to the MySQL server from your own scripts use the following connection parameters”:

- Host : localhost
- Port : 3306
- User : root
- Password : root

**Which I did.**

**Configuration**

- System : Windows 11
- MAMP 4.2.0
- Apache 2.2.31
- MySQL 5.7.24
- PHP 7.4.1
- PhpMyAdmin 4.8.3

In **phpinfo()**:

| mysqlnd | enabled |
| --- | --- |
| API extensions | mysqli,pdo_mysql |

| PDO support | enabled |
| --- | --- |
| PDO drivers | sqlite, mysql |

| PDO Driver for MySQL | enabled |
| --- | --- |
| Client API version | mysqlnd 7.4.1 |

| Pdo_sqlite | enabled |
| --- | --- |
| SQLite Library | 3.30.1 |

In my **php.ini** (located here : *C:\MAMP\conf\php7.4.1\php.ini*), among the extensions that are uncommented I have :

```
extension=php_mysqli.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlite.dll
extension=php_sqlite3.dll
extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll
; ...
; Directory in which the loadable extensions (modules) reside.
extension_dir = "C:\MAMP\bin\php\php7.4.1\ext\"
; ps : I've checked, they're all here
```

Comment: Why are you showing us the phpMyAdmin config? Isn't the issue with your own code?

Comment: Yes the issue is with my own code, I just wanted to provid all the informations I could gather but you can ignore the phpMyAdmin config if it's not usefull

Comment: Are you sure that your `new PDO` and `phpinfo()` are in the same file and executed in the same way? Are you maybe executing one in the browser and the other on CLI?

Comment: Ah yes that seems to be the problem. Now when I call `phpinfo()` from the same folder as my page `home.php`, I get `PDO drivers : no value` but why and how can I fix it? Why does the extension pdo_mysql is not enabled from this path but is enabled from `http://localhost/MAMP/phpinfo.php`  where I originally called it?

Comment: There are two separate ini files. One for Apache and one for CLI. Or maybe you have 2 PHP versions installed in MAMP

Comment: I wish I could say you solved my problem as I realized I was not editing the good `php.ini` (C:\MAMP\conf\php7.4.1\php.ini instead of C:\MAMP\bin\php\php7.4.1\php.ini) but after applying the changes to the good file, I still get `PDO drivers : no value` in `phpinfo()`

Comment: Did you restart Apache?

Comment: Yes I did. After every changes I restarted the servers in MAMP. In the good `php.ini` I've tried to specify the extension without `.dll`, I've tried both relative and absolute path to say where the extensions resides (`extension_dir = "ext"` and `extension_dir = "C:\MAMP\bin\php\php7.4.1\ext"`) but nothing seemed to work

Comment: Make sure you have `ini_set('display_startup_errors', '1');` enabled

Comment: Yes it's already set to `on`

Comment: Could it be that MAMP or Apache doesn't have the right to access the folder containing the extensions ?